# Join 2 tables for viewing

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, group-by

I got 2 tables of recipes, and recipe_ratings 
and I don't know how to get the AVG(rating_value) from recipe_rating 
and join them

Recipes table (get '*') and join it with AVG(recipe_value) 
order by date_posted

Comment: You're better of reading some sql tutorials. SO is not a write my code for me site. Also, without knowing what your tables look like and how they are related, any answer is a wild guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my approach:

**Table & Data :**

```
CREATE TABLE recipes 
    (`id` int, `recipe_name` varchar(7))
;
CREATE TABLE recipe_ratings 
    (`id` int, `recipeId` int,`rating_value` int,`date_posted` datetime)
;

INSERT INTO recipes
    (`id`, `recipe_name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Cake'),
    (2, 'Bun'),
    (3, 'Hot Dog'),
    (4, 'Tea')
;

INSERT INTO recipe_ratings
  (`id`, `recipeId`,`rating_value`,`date_posted`)
VALUES
    (1,1,3,'2015-03-20 10:30:00.000'),
    (2,2,4,'2015-06-20 10:30:00.000'),
    (3,3,5,'2014-03-20 10:30:00.000')
;
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT R.*, AVG(RR.rating_value) rating_value
FROM recipes R
LEFT JOIN recipe_ratings RR ON R.id = RR.recipeId 
GROUP BY RR.date_posted,R.id 
ORDER BY RR.date_posted DESC
```

**SqlFiddle** [**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/27711/3)

Comment: what if there are no rating for that recipe? it will not be joined

Comment: @jonas bro I have fixed that.so if you think its working then please upvote or accept my answer.

Comment: did you see new code jonas

Comment: thanks :) uttam kumar

Comment: best of luck brother

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following query:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.avg(rating) as 'Average Rating' FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 
ON t1.id = t2.id GROUP BY t1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT r.*, AVG(rr.rating_value) rating_value
FROM recipes r
INNER JOIN recipe_ratings rr ON r.recipeId = rr.recipeId 
GROUP BY r.recipeId
```